# End of Statement Expected...VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to open a new window on the client side from vb.net using:

```
Dim webaddress as String
webaddress = "window.open("http://www.google.com")"
Page.Clientscript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "newpage", webaddress, True)
```

I am getting an error "End of statement expected" in line no. 2... Please help.
I have tried all sorts of combinations.

Comment: Replace " with ' with the urls, or escape the ".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle such scenarios using `String.Format`, for clear understanding of where the quotes `"` should be specified:

```
webaddress = String.Format("window.open(""{0}"")", "http://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Missing double quotes?

Comment: @Ripple, yes OP was missing double quotes.

Comment: I mean `"window.open({0})"` should be `"window.open(""{0}"")"`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the double quotes in the URL, like so:

```
webaddress = "window.open(""http://www.google.com"")"
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks but I am curious why do we need double quotes?

Comment: You have 4 double quotes in a single string. Unless you escape those doubles quotes which are part of the **content** of the string, it will be incorrectly parsed as 2 strings - one ending at 'open(' and another starting at 'http', which is what is happening now.

Comment: No worries. Please mark the answer as accepted to indicate that this answer helped solve your issue.